# Bed leveling suggestions given this mesh generated by BLTouch

Tags: bed-leveling, bltouch, creality-cr-10

The printer is a Creality CR-10 S5.

Marlin 2.0.7.2

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the highest point.
[image: high point right side]

Deepest valley
[image: deep valley back]

Further the leveling screws on the right X0,0 and X=0, Y=467 are barely at the very bottom of the screw.  The ones on the left side are cranked super tight nearly at the maximum tightness. The BLTouch is doing a 10x10 grid so the resolution is pretty high.

Any suggestions as to how to get it flatter?  Does anyone else have this issue and resolve it?

I can print with a raft.  Any way to confirm if my bed is actually this bad or sensor glitch.  I obviously can't see at sub-millimeter levels with my eyes.

Could this be an issue with the Z-axis?

So here are the wheel pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

So, I changed the wheels, and re-leveled.  I got this:

[image: after]
Except for about 1 cm of the corner opposite the red side it is level enough to print on.

Comment: Photo of the x-axis and wheels please. Could be a flat wheel

Comment: @Trish I added pictures of the wheels.

Comment: The wheels look as if they need to be replaced...

Comment: @0scar which is why I asked for photos of them :)

Comment: I doubt the corner is 1 cm off-set, this is probably in mm, so it is 0.6 mm! Getting new wheels clearly worked, you should accept the answer of @Trish and delete the last addition to the question and create a new question referring back to this one. In that new question we can elp you further solving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Understanding the pattern

Indeed, it looks like the error is induced by the X-Axis, as the pattern is very uniform over the Y-axis. The most likely reason for such an error is either damage to the rail, or damage to the motion system using the rail.

Damage to the rail would either be a deformed or a deep spot in it.

However, in your case, it is quite easily the wheels being worn down on the leading and lower roller while the trailing one does show to be not pressed against the rail properly. As a result, the print head can possibly might either tilt a little or the contact surfaces of the wheel might no longer run perfectly concentric with the wheel's hub itself and the printhead. In both cases, the head does a little wave dance around the ideal Z-position.

I would try to tighten the rollers, and in either case swap them out for spares.

### After re-fitting

The new mesh leveling tells me that the back right corner needs to go down quite some (about a millimeter) and the whole left can go up a little. The front right looks about right, maybe a little on the low end, but not too much. A BL-touch printer still needs leveling in itself.

Comment: @Trish Changing the wheels seem to even out the center.